# Django syncdb not making tables for my app

Tags: python, django, django-models

It used to work, and now it doesn't. `python manage.py syncdb` no longer makes tables for my app.

From **settings.py**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'mysite.myapp',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)
```

What could I be doing wrong? The break appeared to coincide with editing this model in **models.py**, but that could be total coincidence. I commented out the lines I changed, and it still doesn't work.

```
class MyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    takingReqSets = models.ManyToManyField(RequirementSet, blank=True)
    takingTerms = models.ManyToManyField(Term, blank=True)
    takingCourses = models.ManyToManyField(Course, through=TakingCourse, blank=True)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
#    minCreditsPerTerm = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
#    maxCreditsPerTerm = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
#    optimalCreditsPerTerm = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
```

**UPDATE**:

When I run `python manage.py loadddata initial_data`, it gives an error:

```
DeserializationError: Invalid model identifier: myapp.SomeModel
```

Loading this data had worked fine before. This error is thrown on the very first data object in the data file.

**SOLVED:**

Fixed by removing this line:

```
from stringprep import bl
```

Comment: Does the table  already exist?

Comment: No, I'm deleting the SQLite DB file every time before I run syncdb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd bet that the SomeModel model you mention above (not necessarily MyUser) has got a problem with it which means it can't be imported by loaddata. If not SomeModel, then a model in the same models.py that SomeModel is defined in.

Have you tried `./manage.py validate` ? Even if that says all models are fine, sometimes if there's an error in a models.py of an an app, the entire app becomes 'invisible' to manage.py. I can't say I know *why* this is the case, but seems to ring a bell.

Comment: Validation reports: `0 errors found`. I guess I'll look by hand for other errors.